# Does EntityManager refresh() cause to cascade synchronization through entities multi-level relation?

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0, entitymanager

I have three entities 'A', 'B', 'C':

---

```
@Entity
public class A implements Serializable {
    ... 

    private B b;  

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "a", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Cascade({CascadeType.ALL})
    public B getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public void setB(B b) {
        this.b = b;
    } 

    ...
}
```

---

```
@Entity
public class B implements Serializable {
    ...

    private A a;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public A getA() {
         return a;
    }

    public void setA(A a) {
         this.a = a;
    }

    ...

    private Collection<C> cCollection;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "b", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public Collection<C> getCCollection() {
        return cCollection;
    }

    public void setCCollection(Collection<C> cCollection) {
        this.cCollection = cCollection;
    }
    ...
}
```

---

```
@Entity
public class C implements Serializable {
    ...

    private B b;
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
    public B getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public void setB(B b) {
        this.b= b;
    }
}
```

---

When I update B.cCollection -add or remove C objects- and then refresh object a, I'll expect these changes affect results of a.getB().getCCollection(), but it never happens and cCollection list won't be updated. Am I wrong with refresh() operation?

```
//Adding or removal C objects to/from a.getB().getCCollection()
//Persisting changes
myEM.refresh(a);
```

(Note: I use hibernate and JPA 2.0. Persisting data in database has no problem and works truly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use merge method instead: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html

```
myEM.merge(a);
```

Comment: Yeah, didn't notice you don't set cascade for b.getCCollection(). You can set cascade property or call merge on b.

Comment: Btw, when you update C objects from a.getB().getCCollection(), is your A object a managed object?

Comment: Logically, if I refresh 'a' all basic and relational field of it must be refreshed!!(Please correct if I'm wrong). So when I call a.getB().getCCollection(), it must return new collection of c (new persisted collection). Should I refresh 'b' object of 'a', too?

Comment: For example: `a.getB().getCCollection().add(new C(/*arguments*/)); myEM.getTransaction().begin(); myEM.merge(a.getB()); myEM.getTransaction().commit(); myEM.refresh(a)`

Comment: refresh only means it retrieves objects' states from database instead of session. So before you call refresh(), are you sure your change has been flushed to database?

Comment: I'm sure that the changes have been flushed- new record added to table 'c'- before I call refresh(). What do you think about refreshing 'b', too?

Comment: Yeah, then you need to call refresh on b. Otherwise, add a cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH to b.getCCollection()

Comment: I added '@Cascacde({cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH})' to  'b.getCCollection()' and it's working well. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

"It is possible to re-load an object and all its collections at any time, using the refresh() method. This is useful when database triggers are used to initialize some of the properties of the object."

"How much does Hibernate load from the database and how many SQL SELECTs will it use? This depends on the fetching strategy."

More details by accessing [Chapter 10: Working with Objects](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html)